# Comprobar si modelos están relacionados

Tags: ruby-on-rails

tengo dos tablas una llamada Post y la otra Payments, estas están relacionadas, Post tiene muchos Payments, si en tal caso se llega a borrar un Post, el Payment relacionado a este Post obviamente se borra, lo que me gustaría hacer es si en dado caso el Post tiene algún Payment, que se deshabilite el boton de eliminar del index de Post(que el usuario no pueda borrarlo para que no se borre el payment) , y que si no tiene algún payment relacionado, que se borre.¿como podría hacer esto? si alguien me ayuda por fa, he estado intentando hacerlo de la siguiente manera pero me dice que payment esta nulo

```
<% if post.id != payment.post_id %>
<%= link_to 'Eliminar', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: '¿Esta seguro que desea eliminar este post?' } %><%end%><%end%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hola LuisC. No entiendo bien tu pregunta, primero dices *payments tiene muchos Post* y luego dices *en tal caso se llega a borrar un Post, el Payment relacionado a este Post obviamente se borra* pero esto no tiene sentido puesto que en tu primera sentencia dices que un payment tiene varios posts, la dependencia es de post hacia payments, no al revés. Por favor corregir la redacción para poder comprender mejor el problema en cuestión.

Comment: Hola @LuiggiMendoza tienes razon, ya lo corregi. es posible corroborar que si el post tiene algun payment?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear una validación personalizada en tu modelo Post y hacer que solo se utilice con la acción *destroy* en tu controlador Posts. Esto no 'deshabilitará' el botón 'borrar' en la forma, pero no permitirá que se borre el Post cuando haya Payments.

```
# app/models/post.rb

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :payments, dependent: :destroy
  validate :no_payments, on: :destroy # <= Aquí llamas tu validación

  def no_payments
    errors.add(:post_con_payments, "Post con payments") if
    self.payments.count > 0
  end
end

# app/models/payment.rb

class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

Aunque no puse este código a prueba, pienso que debe funcionar. En caso contrario, podemos buscar otra opción.

Answer (score 0):

Si tus modelos están relacionados con `belongs_to` y `has_many`, deberías ser capaz de saberlo fácilmente con:

`if post.payments ...`

Con esa instrucción sacarías todos los pagos relacionados con un post. También puedes usar un `post.payments.count` para saber el número de pagos.

Si no están relacionados así, deberían estarlo!!